# Move to next cell in the next row in excel using c#

Tags: c#, excel, automation, pia

How can I move to the next row in Excel using C#. I'm using Office PIA v 14. When I used Range.Next property, it takes me to the cell immediately right to the range. How can I move to the next row? ie. the cell immediately below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Range.Next returns a Range object that represents the **next cell**.

I'm not really the greatest expert alive but according to the documentation you should use Offset instead. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.offset

Here is some pseudo code

```
var excelApp = this.Application;
int skipRows = 1;
int skipCells = 0;
var nextRange = excelApp.ActiveCell.Offset[skipRows, skipCells].Select();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
Range oRng = ws.get_Range(Column + (row +1), Type.Missing);
```

where `ws` is the worksheet object.